# youtube-dl for python: How can I get the error code for no video results?

Tags: python, discord.py, youtube-dl

I'm using youtube-dl for my discord bot and i'm using `default_search: auto` for searching videos. But my problem is when I search something nonsense like adhsdgfasj it returns this to console : 
`ERROR: [youtube] No video results`. I want to handle this error and when this error occurs I want the bot to say things like "No video results" but since this doesnt give me an error code like something i can use in try: except: I can't handle it. Can you help me ?

Answer (score 2):

What options are you giving youtube dl. If you want to catch exception you need to set `ignoreerrors` to `True`

```
opts = {
    'ignoreerrors': False
}

youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(opts)
```

This will make it so you can catch exceptions given by youtube-dl.

Another way you could go about this is check if the return value is `None` or if the return dict has anything in the `retval["entries"]` list. When both evaluate to False no results were found.